# JScript Documentation

Tags: documentation

Note: NOT Javascript. :-)

---

Hello,

I just had a random thought, and have decided to learn more Jscript. I know the basics, I'm proficient in HTML, XML and C++ BUT, there doesn't seem to be much docs on Jscript. The official MS Documentation for JScript contains a WHOPPING ONE WHOLE PAGE about web-page development in Jscript! And that page, is useless.

Is this the right documentation? I downloaded it from Microsoft's website. I have no idea where to go for descent docs related to Jscript, nothing on Gooogle, nothing in book shops, nothing anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, this post is now locked -- but for anyone in the future who's trying to find documentation on the global objects available in JScript, you may find this useful. It's documentation on the top level objects available to WSH, the Windows Script Host environment, in which JScript and VBScript run.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//98591fh7%28v%3dvs.85%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen these [detailed docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a(VS.71).aspx)? They look quite comprehensive to me.

There are additional pointers to information in the references of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#External_links).

There also seem to be [several books available](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=jscript&x=0&y=0).

Comment: Thank you. I have read those a few times, and also seen the Wikipedia page too. I just feel that there is something missing. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @baeltazor: No problem. Sorry it wasn't what you were hoping for.